# Why The function is returning False for None objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function which should check if the incoming object is allowed or not.

Why this Function Failing For None Type.

```
def is_valid_object(obj):
    allowed_types = [int, bool, None]
    return type(obj) in allowed_types
```

**Working for:**

`is_valid_object('i am string')` Expected `False` => Returns `False`

`is_valid_object(10)` Expected `True`  => Returns `True`

`is_valid_object(False)` Expected `True` => Returns `True`

---

#### Why This Fails:

`is_valid_object(None)` Expected `True` => Returns `False`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`None` is not a type, it's the single value of the `NoneType` type. Use `type(None)` to access that type to put it in your allowed types list:

```
allowed_types = [int, bool, type(None)]
```

In my view is is better to just explicitly test for the `None` singleton with `obj is None`, as that's much clearer in intent:

```
allowed_types = [int, bool]
return obj is None or type(obj) in allowed_types
```

Instead of using `type(obj) in allowed_types`, consider using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) with a tuple second argument:

```
def is_valid_object(obj):
    return obj is None or isinstance(obj, (int, bool))
```

which can be simplified to:

```
def is_valid_object(obj):
    return obj is None or isinstance(obj, int)
```

because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Demo:

```
>>> def is_valid_object(obj):
...     return obj is None or isinstance(obj, int)
...
>>> is_valid_object(42)
True
>>> is_valid_object(False)
True
>>> is_valid_object(None)
True
>>> is_valid_object('Hello world!')
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the `int` and `bool`, `type(None)` is not equal to `None`

```
print(type(None))
```

> NoneType

To workaround you can do:

```
def is_valid_object(obj):
    allowed_types = [int, bool, type(None)]
    return type(obj) in allowed_types
```

---

**Output**:

```
print(is_valid_object(None))
```

> True

Comment: `type(10)` isn't equal to `10`, either. `type(x) == x` is only true if `x` is `type` itself.

Answer (score 0):

`None` is a value, not a type. There is no built-in name for the type of `None`. Use either

```
def is_valid_object(obj):
    allowed_types = [int, bool, type(None)]
    return type(obj) in allowed_types
```

or (Python 2 only)

```
from types import NoneType

def is_valid_object(obj):
    allowed_types = [int, bool, NoneType]
    return type(obj) in allowed_types
```

Either way, your function can be simplified (and made more correct) by using `isinstance` rather than type comparison.

```
def is_vali_object(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, (int, bool, type(None)))
```

(Since `None` is the *only* value of its type, though, it's easier to check `obj is None` directly as [Martijn Pieters shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55668225/1126841).)